# How to multiply $variable that includes € with a value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

since I'm new to PHP I have a quite simple question. After Googling and searching here on stackoverflow I still can't get it to work.

```
<?php 
    $payinfront = $product->get_price_html();
    $totalprice = $payinfront * 2;
?>

<p class="price">Total price: <?php echo $totalprice ?></p>
<p class="price">Amount to pay in front: <?php echo $payinfront ?></p>
<p class="price">Amount to pay after: <?php echo $totalprice - $payinfront ?></p>
```

The $payinfront value does get it's value from another part of my template. Let's say it's €10,-. This is the amount people have to pay in front. When we have done the service they have to pay the other half wich is the last rule.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: so get_price_html() returns the price formatted with the currency sign? does get_price() exist? We may need to see more of your product class.

Comment: get_price_html() does indeed return the price including the currency sign. The code comes in from the wordpress plugin Woocommerce, do I need to show the code from get_price_html(); here?

Comment: I don't have any experience with that plugin but try changing that line to $product->price; that may work. I would *strongly* advise checking for the correct way to do this instead of using a str_replace to remove the currency sign as some of the answers are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store prices as [floats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), not as strings, so that PHP can recognize them as numeric values, and do calculations on them. Only cast them to strings at the very last moment, when you are `echo`ing them in your template.

```
<?php
    $payInFront = $product->getPrice(); // should return a numeric value, instead of a string
    $totalPrice = $payInFront * 2;
    $payAfter   = $totalPrice - $payInFront;
?>
```

Then, when you `echo` the prices, you might want to format them in a certain way, using [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
<p>Price: &euro; <?php echo number_format($totalPrice, 2, ',', '.'); ?></p>
```

Comment: This code works, I only had to change getPrice(); to get_price(); But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the currency symbol before multiplication:

```
$totalprice =  substr($payinfront, 1) * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<?php 
    $payinfront = $product->get_price_html();
    $totalprice = $payinfront * 2;
?>

<p class="price">Total price: &euro;<?php echo $totalprice ?></p>
<p class="price">Amount to pay in front: &euro;<?php echo $payinfront ?></p>
<p class="price">Amount to pay after: &euro;<?php echo $totalprice - $payinfront ?></p>
```

Note that `&euro;` makes an euro sign

Comment: The problem isn't the € sign. $totalprice has a value of €10,- but when I echo $totalprice the value it prints is 0. So it seems the code doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to remove the euro sign so that the variable can be considered a number. Then you make the multiplication and concatenate the euro sign below at the html part.

```
<?php 
    $payinfront = $product->get_price_html();
    $payinfront = str_replace("&euro;","",$payinfront);
    $totalprice = $payinfront * 2;
?>

<p class="price">Total price: <?php echo $totalprice ?>&euro;</p>
<p class="price">Amount to pay in front: <?php echo $payinfront ?>&euro;</p>
<p class="price">Amount to pay after: <?php echo $totalprice - $payinfront ?>&euro;</p>
```